# cannot view partitions after rsync restore: how to backup better?

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync

I have done a backup using rsync and restored the system as a test. All went well except that I cannot click on the partition listing in nautilus anymore. When I do it complains about "This location cannot be displayed. You do not have the permission necessary to view the contents". Opening nautilus as root gives no such problem. My backup command was:

```
sudo rsync -av --one-file-system --hard-links --human-readable --numeric-ids --progress /media/myext4usbkey/backup /dev/sda5myubuntupartition
```

What do I need to do next time so I don't run into this problem anymore?

To clarify, I'm not asking for a better backup tool or how rsync would compare with other tools, just how I can solve this problem using rsync.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) especially [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/2634/344926) that deals with `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are visible to users in the group `disk`. If you were in that group before you should still be if you saved and restored files in /etc. You can see which groups you are in with the command`id`. To add group `disk` to your user id do

```
sudo usermod -aG disk $USER
```

You will need to login to see the change.

Comment: In a fresh  install this is the output of `id`: `uid=1000(koen) gid=1000(koen) groups=1000(koen),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),131(sambashare)`. I can see partitions now though.

Comment: @koen ok.  I dont know what else it could be then. some simple things are just too complicated nowadays...